# RelationalDatabases and dates (Mathematica 12)

Tags: date-and-time, entity, databases

As related to the new database functionality in version 12, I am trying to retrieve a specific entity (row) or group of entities (multiple rows) between a date range in an MS SQL database. The database I am looking at has 4 columns, `"SKUNumber"`, `"Quantity"`, `"Price"`, `"SoldDate"`. How can I construct a query (`EntityFuncton`?) to do that?

The equivalent SQL query would have the `WHERE` clause be:

```
WHERE SKUNumber = '1111' 
   AND SoldDate > '2019-05-31 00:00:00.000' 
   AND SoldDate < '2019-09-01 00:00:00.000'
```

The [quick guide](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RelationalDatabasesQuickStart.html) can be found:

Thanks!

Comment: Just use DatabaseLink`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Admittedly the date and time support for the new relational databases is not yet exactly where we would like it to be.

Under the following assumptions

- You have already registered the database ( as described e.g. in the tutorial you linked)
- Your `"SoldDate"` column is of the type `DATE`, not `DATETIME`
- You actually wanted the *less*, not *greater*, inequality sign in the last clause

The query you need will be as follows:

```
EntityValue[
  FilteredEntityClass[
    "your-table",
    EntityFunction[o, 
      And[
        o["SKUNumber"] == "1111", 
        o["SoldDate"] > DateObject[
           Take[DateList["2019-05-31 00:00:00.000"], 3]
        ] ,
        o["SoldDate"] < DateObject[
           Take[DateList["2019-09-01 00:00:00.000"], 3]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ],
  {"SKUNumber", "Quantity", "Price", "SoldDate"}
]
```

where it is important to note that the `Take[DateList[...]]` part is evaluated on the Wolfram Language side, before the query gets compiled to SQL and executed.

Comment: Leonid, thank you for the detailed answer. I think adding Date & Time support is quite vital with respect to most SQL work. Thank you!

Comment: @MathematicaUser I agree. The work is underway regarding that.